# How do I search for values in a dictionary

Tags: c#

what would be the best way to search for a value in a dictionary.
for instance I would like to search for modified objects, would going through the entire collection be the only way to do this?

c#, .net 2.0

```
class RecA
 { 
 public bool modified {get;set:}
 public string txt {get;set;}
 }

class RecA_Dic : Dictionary<int,Rec_A>
{

   public bool GetItemByKey(int key,out obj)
   {
    return   this.TryGetValue(key, out obj);
    }

   public List<Rec_A> getModifiedItems()
   {
     List<Rec_A> li = new List<Rec_A>();
     for(int i=0;i<this.count;i++)
      if (((Rec_A)this[i]).modified == true)
       li.Add((Rec_A)this[i]);
     return li;
   }

}
```

Comment: Dictionary<> has no indexer[int], unless its key type is int.

Comment: ...and in that case, [int] isn't doing what you think it is!

Comment: @Humberto: the key type *is* an int in the example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given the constraints (.NET 2.0), you are almost on target. `IEnumerable<Rec_A>` plus `yield return` is a better alternative, IMO:

```
public IEnumerable<Rec_A> getModifiedItems()
{
  foreach (Rec_A rec in this.Values)
  {
     if (rec.modified)
        yield return rec;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is very clean but one warning: If, for some reason, identifying modified records means he has to remove them from the dictionary, this enumeration will throw.

Comment: Wondering how you would change this for post 2.0

Comment: Me too, @Greg. I'm totally unaware of LINQ.

Comment: Not related to this question, but the references to the modified items can be modified from the outside (i.e changed the modified property from outside the class after it is retrieved). How will the implementation look, if it will return a readonly copy of the modified elements?

Comment: @Greg, @Humberto: post 2.0 aka w/Linq `return this.Values.Where(kvp => kvp.modified);` Call `.ToList()` to get a concrete list to avoid pitfalls mentioned by n8wrl.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a dictionary only has a fast lookup for the key. If you want to look for anything in the value, you have to loop through the entire collection.

If you do this a lot, you could put a list in your collection that keeps track of only the modified items. It will be a little more overhead when modifying the collection as the list has to be updated also, but getting just the modified items will be very fast.

Answer (score 1):

Searching through the entire dictionary is certainly the simplest way of doing it, though a `foreach` loop would be cleaner:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Rec_A> kvp in d)
{
    // Check kvp.Value
}
```

If you want lookups to be faster you could add your modified objects in a separate list at the time you modify them. This will slow down modifications though, so there is a trade-off involved here.

Answer (score 1):

The basic answer to your question is yes, you have to iterate through the values to find the modified ones.

Now the rest of this answer is going to read like a code review.  So many warning bells went off in my head when I read your code that I felt compelled to do so.

1) First off your code will on even work.  That's because you are treating the keys into the `Dictionary` like indexes into a `List` or `Array`.  Your `for` loop starts `i` at 0 and increments it to the `Count` (which is the number of `KeyValuePair`s by the way).  But what if I don't have a value in the `Dictionary` with a key equal to 0?  Basically you'll get an exception for something like this:

```
RecA_Dic myD = new RecA_Dic();
myD.Add(10,new Rec_A());
myD.getModifiedItems(); //throws KeyNotFoundException
```

Now if you are adding values into the `Dictionary` with a zero based index then that begs the question of why use a `Dictionary` when a `List` would do?

2) You don't need to do the casts on `this[i]`.  Because you told the `Dictionary` that it will contain `Rec_A` values, it will return the values as `Rec_A`.  That's the beauty of generics.

3) You don't need to compare `modified` to `true` in the `if` statement.  When working with `bool` variables is is typically considered good etiquette to not compare them to `true` or `false`.  On a side note you might want to consider renaming `modified` to `IsModified`.  That better adheres to many standard naming conventions and makes the code more readable.

4) Whenever possible try to use `foreach` instead of `for`.  In this case a `foreach` would actually fix the problem I mentioned in 1.

5) As Humberto mentioned you might want to consider returning `IEnumerable` and using `yield return`.  This gives you the benefit of delayed execution.

6) Finally why are you even inheriting from `Dictionary`?  Based on your code I would guess you could just create a `Dictionary` and make your `getModified` method `static` and make it take the `Dictionary` (or `List` if that's all you really need) as a parameter.

I hope some of my suggestions will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Either you have to check every value, or you'll have to track changes in another data structure, such as a list of modified objects.  (You could hide it within your specialized dictionary implementation.)

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate Mark Byers response:
e.g. 
Lets say that we have a class named Family which holds some values (no matter how many) and we built a Dictionary to hold its data.
If we like to search through this list we write:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Family> kvPair in familyListDictionary)
        {
            if (kvPair.Key == "4")
            {
                Console.WriteLine (kvPair);
            }
        }
```

And if we search for key "4"... (In my case TKey is a string).